# Closed images of linearly ordered spaces

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, linear-orders

Is there a description of the class of continuous closed images of linearly ordered spaces?

Comment: In the compact case you have Rudin's theorem: The Hausdorff images of compact LOTS's are exactly the compact monotonically normal spaces.